# Accept Error When Duplicate Item Is Trying To Be Added To Database

Tags: c#, database

I made a signup form and when ever I try to make a duplicate name it won't let me, which is good. But I want the user to know that the username was already taken and it wont let them. How do I do that?
Heres the code I use:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"NOTSHOWING");
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Schools(Username,Password,Security,SecurityQuestion) values ('" + bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text + "','" + bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue + "')", con);
     Form5 ss = new Form5();
     ss.Show();
     Thread.Sleep(5000);
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
```

And the error I get:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 
'NOTSHOWING'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Schools'. The 
duplicate key value is (NAME).
The statement has been terminated.'
```

And also, can I try and catch multiple blocks? Like:

```
try
{

}
catch
{

}
try
{

}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: Trapping exceptions as logic is generally poor design. I would write a stored procedure that inserts the user if they don't exist and use a return code to determine success.

Comment: Crowcoder is right that you should not rely on exceptions for things that you expect to happen under normal circumstances. Rather than using a stored procedure, I'd probably first issue a query to the database to determine whether a user exists with that name, and only perform the INSERT if there are no matching users.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection.  Get rid of that display form and sleep call, it's blocks your code and annoys the user.

Comment: I'll reiterate that you should not use exceptions to drive any kind of logic, but you absolutely can't assume all exceptions mean the user already exists, only a primary key violation would mean that.

Comment: @AA AA Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exception and use that to generate your response rather than just let it propagate back to the user.

This would mean a try/catch around the ExecuteNonQuery call, and then manipulating your result page in whatever way (I can answer the DB question but not the tell you how to do the web part of this).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a `try/catch` block or some form of exception handling.  Example: `try` to do the sql statement, if an exception occurred then it will activate the `catch` block of code.  In the catch block u can inform ur user that it was incorrect based on that exact sqlexception.

The purpose of this is to allow your program to keep running instead of encountering the exception.  Not sure how well this applies to your code specifically, but it would look syntactically similar to this:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"NOTSHOWING");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Schools(Username,Password,Security,SecurityQuestion) values ('" + bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text + "','" + bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue + "')", con);
    Form5 ss = new Form5();
    ss.Show();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

}
catch  //can have () here to tell exception expected
{
    //Inform user or other logic down here continuing the program if there was an exception
    Console.WriteLine("Exception occured.. continuing..");
    //MyLabel.Text = "INVALID";
}
```

Also you can do something like this:

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2627)
    {
        //Violation of primary key. Handle Exception
    }
    else throw;
}
```

[MSSQL_ENG002627](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151757(v=sql.100).aspx)

Or if you want to catch multiple ones you can structure your try catch to look like this:

```
    try
    {
       // ...
      throw new InvalidOperationException(
         "Arbitrary exception");
       // ...
   }
   catch(System.Web.HttpException exception)
     when(exception.GetHttpCode() == 400)
   {
     // Handle System.Web.HttpException where
     // exception.GetHttpCode() is 400.
   }
   catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
   {
     bool exceptionHandled=false;
     // Handle InvalidOperationException
     // ...
     if(!exceptionHandled)
       // In C# 6.0, replace this with an exception condition
     {
        throw;
     }
    }
```

As illustrated by [Mark Michaelis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt620018.aspx)..

Lastly, using exception handling to drive the logic may be a strategically unwise choice, and there may be better ways of structuring your code that won't lead bad things..(see @LarsTech ..@Crowcoder 's comments.)